# django ,implementing checkbox into admin.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, checkbox

[(img)i'd like the checkbox inside list_display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Rs0.png) 
inside django,i'd like to add a checkbox to my list_display for each instance of **unicode** (which is an email adress).

this is my models.py file inside my 'joins' app :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# from smtplib import *
from django.db import models






class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    # BoolField = models.NullBooleanField()
```

this is ny admin.py file inside my 'joins' app :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Join


class JoinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =['__unicode__','timestamp','updated']

    @property
    class Meta:
        model = Join
        abstract = True
admin.site.register(Join, JoinAdmin)
```

Comment: What do you want the checkbox to do?

Comment: i want it to check if an email is selected (ofc) and if its selected i'll send a pre programmed message to all those emails from my domain.

Answer (score 0):

Django already provides a checkbox for each item in the admin. To write new actions that can be performed when the checkbox is ticked, see the [admin actions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).